# MFMailComposeViewController sends email without attachment

Tags: ios, pdf, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have made a pdf file within code, and I am sending it as an attachment to an email address. When it shows the `MFMailComposeController`, the attachment is there in the email, but it is not attached with the email I receive. What can be the possible reason for this? I have attached the code here.

```
    if(
       [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        [mailViewController setSubject:@"Maintenance Request Form"];
        mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate=self;
            [mailViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"BRE@appiwork.com"]];


        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/MaintenanceRequest.pdf"];

        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];

        [mailViewController addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"MaintenanceRequest.pdf"];

        [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

Comment: How big is the attachment? Many email providers have a limit of 5, 10, or 15 MB. A PDF with some images can easily get bigger than the limit.

Comment: The pdf just has 5 6 lines of text, nothing else

Comment: Have you verified that `data` is not `nil`? Change your `file` variable to this: `NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MaintenanceRequest.pdf"];`

Comment: I've run into this same exact problem, except with a CSV attachment instead of a PDF. The attachment would always appear on the email draft, but sometimes it would not get sent in the email.

I found the problem was that my CSV file was getting corrupted by a bad string. Can you double check that your attachment is not getting corrupted or is otherwise invalid sometimes? (@rmadddy - thanks)